# How to detect when user try to scroll items in listview after reaching the last item also

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am try to detect when user try to scroll the items to top in listview after reaching lastitem also.

sample code:

```
var listview = new ListView ();

listview.ItemsSource = Items;
listview.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) =>
{
   if(isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
       return;

   //hit bottom!
   if(e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
   {
       LoadItems();
   } 
}
```

Comment: At least include code for a sample or an attempt. This site isn't here for people to write code for you.

Comment: Just to let you know I do have an answer for this, if you share a little bit of code and make a bit more of an effort I would be willing to share it. Well something that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Ruddy. I am trying with listview Item appearing event but it detects last item. Any I will update the question.

Comment: That is also what I have. Its the best way I can think of to know when a user has hit both top and bottom. So whats wrong with this code? I will post my code and we can have a look if its not what you need.

Comment: Yes of course, It detect when reach last item but requirement try to scroll after last item in a list. Actually my requirement is I have multiple categoreis at top and I have show each category details. When user try to scroll first cartegory details exceeds last items need to move to next category. Thats why need to detect after last item in listview.

Comment: That is different from the question you have asked. You will have to provide more code so we can see what you mean by categories in a listview. Try to explain it a little better and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

So as your updated question now has I believe its best way to handle what you want.

This is what I came up with. What else do you want it to do?

```
ObservableCollection<int> ListOfItems = new ObservableCollection<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   ListOfItems.Add(i);
}

// Listview
var listView = new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = ListOfItems
};

// What item are we on?
listView.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) =>
{
    if ((int)e.Item == ListOfItems[0])
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("First Item has been hit!");
    }

    if ((int)e.Item == ListOfItems[ListOfItems.Count - 1])
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("Last Item has been hit!");
    }
};
```

**Notes:** On a small screen you will hit both first item and last items "events" straight away.

Comment: This one detect when we reach last item. Please take fallowing scenario then you can understand. I have number items in a list. each items is able to adding. if we write like this user not able add last items because when he try to reach last item in list we are move to next category details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you by "when he try to reach last item in list we are move to next category details". What do you mean next category? What does the listview do then?

Comment: Sorry for late. This is my scenario. In my xaml page at top I have to show number of tabs and each tabs inside list of details.If want to show second tab details you want to select second tab then it will display related date below of these tabs. Now what I am trying is when user scroll to bottom of the position in first tab details then it will detect and call the second tab. So it automatically show second tab details. Here each tab list of details is able to adding option like voting feature in this site.

Comment: Because of that if I am using fallowing code user not able select select last item. So we will detect when user try to scroll the items exceeds the items in list view. I hope you can understanding my situation. If you have any confusion please try to ask. Thank you.